# React Use State hook with user authentication

Tags: reactjs

Im learning react and im mucking around with google authentication with passport js.

So pretty much when the user lands on my page, they're not authenticated so i have a button to ask them to sign in via google. Once they are logged in, i'll redirect them to my homepage with their name and simply say they are logged in and it shows a button to log out.

Now this is the issue, after i logged them out, i set my state back to false but it keeps rendering back to the home page with their name and log in message.

I somehow fixed it with the spread operator but i dont know why it works. I cant seem to wrap my head around it.

Can someone please share some light on it? Cheers.

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as api from '../api/index';
import Header from './Header';

function Home() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    user: {},
    error: null,
    authenticated: false
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLoggedInUser = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await api.loginSucess();
        setUser({ authenticated: true, user: data.user });
      } catch (error) {
        setUser({ authenticated: false, error: 'Failed to authenticate user' });
      }
    };
    fetchLoggedInUser();
  }, []);

  const handleNotAuthenticated = () => {
    setUser(...user, { authenticated: false });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header
        authenticated={user.authenticated}
        handleNotAuthenticated={handleNotAuthenticated}
      />
      <div>
        {!user.authenticated ? (
          'Welcome'
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h1>You have sucessfully logged in</h1>
            <h2>Welcome {user.user.firstName}</h2>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: `setUser` takes an object but you are spreading an object (`user`) directly into it which should be a syntax error. Did you mean to write `setUser({ ...user, authenticated: false })`?

Comment: i didnt error out when i compiled my client side code though. Thats weird. As soon as i fixed the code as setUser({ ...user, authenticated: false }), when i log out, my homepage keeps re-rendering with the log in message